# Simplify Database design

Tags: sql, database-design

Could anyone suggest a good design for these 4tables.

Design

```
 Fields: DesignId (Primarykey),
Iname..,....
```

Table2 :InputFiles

```
FileId int,
DesignId ,
FileName,
Description,
primary key (FileId,DesignId )
foreign key(DesignId)...
//This foreign key here seems to cause insert problems.
```

Table3 : InputData

```
DesignId int,
TestCaseInputId,
FileId int,
MaterialType,
primary key(DesignId ,TestCaseInputId,FileId)
foreign key(FileId ) references InputFiles
foreign key(DesignId) refernces Design
```

Questions:

1. I am not sure or convinced about the composite keys in Table2, Table3.
2. Foreign Keys.The foreign keys seem to cause a insertion problem

Comment: It's difficult to tell what is being asked here.  Is there a certain problem that you are facing?  Simply stating your design and asking people to `spot the potential bug` is [not how we do things here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129787/172936)

Comment: What 4 tables? I see only three: Design, InputFiles and InputData. Also, what exactly is the nature of your "insertion problem".

Comment: Foreign keys don't cause *insertion problems* - they protect data integrity by prohibiting inserting data that references non-existing rows in a referenced table...

Answer (score 1):

Saying "The foreign keys seem to cause a [sic] insertion problem" does not help.  What is the problem?  I would speculate that the issue is the order of loading data, rather than the foreign key constraint.  You need to be sure that the id exists *before* you load the data with it.

When reading data from files, I usually use the following strategy:

1. Load the data into temporary, all-character staging tables.
2. Validate the data in the staging tables, including foreign keys and types.
3. Add any missing primary keys to the appropriate table, if necessary.
4. Load the data into the final tables.

This requires more steps and data movement.  However, I am continually reminded of how much real time is saved by doing proper checking on input data.

Answer (score 1):

No one can really make a design from so little knowledge of the use scenarios...but

Some pseudo DDL, not sure which server you use...

```
create table Design (
    DesignID int not null primary key,
    Iname nvarchar(32) not null
)

create table InputFile (
    FileID int not null primary key,
    DesignID int not null, -- foreign key referencing Design (DesignID)
    FileName nvarchar(max) not null,
    Description nvarchar(max) null
)

create table InputData (
    TestCaseInputID int not null primary key,
    FileID int not null,  -- Foreign key referencing InputFile (FileID)
    MaterialType nvarchar(?)
)
```

The main point is don't make the InputFile primary key (FileID,DesignID) unless you intend to have more than one file with the same FileID.

Having DesignID in InputData is not necessary, redundant. If you put it there you have to insure it remains consistent with InputFile.DesignID. You still may want it if this relationship never changes. That's just a hint of normalization.

You must insert data in order as follows...

1. First Insert Design
2. Then insert File
3. Then insert InputData

Why is InputData a separate table from InputFile? If you will multiple input data rows for each file then it makes sense.

You might want to make DesignID, FileID, and TestCaseInputID identity columns or your server's equivalent auto-incrementing int ids. Or if these ids are real world information obtained elsewhere then you must insert them.